# functions send converging sequences to converging sequences proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Need to prove that $f(z) \to a$ as $z\to z_0$ if and only if the sequence $(f(z_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$ for every sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $z_0$. Intuitively I know that functions send converging sequences to converging sequences, but I am having trouble completing this proof for my **complex** analysis course.  Is the proof similar to that of real numbers?  Any help on how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: Use dollar signs "$" to enter formulas. As it is now your post it is almost impossible to understand.

Comment: The proof of the theorem in question works in any metric space. However, your idea that all functions send convergent sequences to convergent sequences is wrong: a discontinuous function need not have this property.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=a$ and let $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{z_n}=z_0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta$ such that $|z-z_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(z)-a|<\varepsilon$. For $n$ large enough you have $|z-z_n|<\delta$ so that $|f(z_n)-a|<\varepsilon$ and thus $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{f(z_n)}=a$. Now, let us suppose that
$$ \exists\varepsilon_0,\forall\delta>0,\exists z\in\mathbb{C},|z-z_0|<\delta \text{ and } |f(z)-a|\geqslant\varepsilon_0 $$ Taking $\delta=\frac{1}{n+1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ gives us a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{z_n}=z_0$ and $|f(z_n)-a|\geqslant\varepsilon_0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By contraposition we have proved the result.